# WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component

Tags: interface, jboss7.x, affinity

### Module 1 Server Side

```
public interface BaseInterface{
  Customer createCustomer(Profile profile);
}

public interface InterfaceA extends BaseInterface{
}

public class ServiceProducer {  
    @EJB(lookup = "java:global/path/ClassA")
    @Produces
    private InterfaceA interfaceA;
}

@Remote(ClassA.class)
public class ClassA implements InterfaceA{
    
    BaseInterface base;

    @Inject
    public ClassA(@Named BaseInterface base){
        this.base = base;
    }
    @Override
    createCustomer implementation ...
}
```

---

Module 2  Client

```
public class Api{
    @Inject
    InterfaceA intA;
    
    @Override
    Customer createCustomer(arg){
        intA.createCustomer
    }
}
```

Hi I am getting the below error when running the above

StatelessEJBLocator for "ClassA", view is interface InterfaceA, affinity is Local

WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component WorkflowManager for method public abstract Customer    BaseInterface.createCustomer(Profile): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance